# VTK: small cosy in a corner instead of the middle

Tags: vtk

Is it possible to have the vtkAxesActor small in a corner of the window?

[image]

Here is a image of what I currently got and what I would like to have. The colorful axes are the standard axesActor. But I would like the axes in a corner of the window and only there (bottom left in black). They shouldn't move around the window when the view is rotated. Only around their origin.

Is this possible? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to put the `vtkAxesActor` into an orientation widget:

```py
    widget = vtk.vtkOrientationMarkerWidget()
    widget.SetOrientationMarker(axisActor)
    widget.SetInteractor(interactor)
    widget.SetViewport(0, 0, size, size)
    widget.InteractiveOff()
    widget.EnabledOn()
```

Comment: Thank you! But some things broke and I have no clue why. The renderered object now isn't in frame anymore after starting + The widget can be moved/resized even though Interactive was set to Off + I get a warning saying that Interactor and enabled should be set before changing interaction. I have no clue why any of this happens.

Comment: Check out the order in which the interactor and the widgets are set up here: https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python/Widgets/OrientationMarkerWidget

Comment: Thanks! The warning was displayed because widget.EnabledOn() was called after widget.InteractiveOff(). Just switching those two lines removed the warning and made the widget not moveable/resizeable. Calling renderer.ResetCamera() gets the displayed object back into frame.

Answer (score 0):

The vtkAxesActor location is functional and it's location has a purpose. The anchor point of the AxesActor is the anchor point of the model. This provides context of where any transformations or translations would be calculated from.

Unfortunately the example of the axisActor in the corner you have proposed would only provide context of the orientation of the model and so not part of the standard options.